# How can I set the state of the previous React Navigation screen on the current screen?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-context, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React Navigation to work with routes in my project. I have a Login screen and a List screen. I searched on the docs of React Navigation and found the following snippet to do such authentication:

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="List" component={List} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
  </>
)
```

I want to know the best way to set the variable (or state?) `isLoggedIn` in the routes file. And I want to change the value of `isLoggedIn` to `true` when the user hits the login button on the Login screen (to make the navigation to the List component).

Comment: Say hello to some state management like Redux or MobX

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. Please read more documentation. Checkout "reset" method [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset).